# How do i calculate a rolling sum by group with monthly data in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I am trying to use rolling().sum() to create a dataframe with 2-month rolling sums within each 'type'. Here's what my data looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
                   'date': ['2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-04-01',
                            '2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-04-01',
                            '2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-04-01'],
                   'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]})
```

and here is the expected result:

[image: expected result]

and here is what I have tried (unsuccessfully):

```
rolling_sum = df.groupby(['date', 'type']).rolling(2).sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: `df.groupby('type')['value'].rolling(2, min_period=1).sum()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```py
rolling_sum = (
    df.assign(value=df.groupby(['type'])['value']
    .rolling(2, min_periods=1).sum().reset_index()['value'])
)
```

Output:

```
   type        date  value
0     A  2022-01-01    1.0
1     A  2022-02-01    3.0
2     A  2022-03-01    5.0
3     A  2022-04-01    7.0
4     B  2022-01-01    5.0
5     B  2022-02-01   11.0
6     B  2022-03-01   13.0
7     B  2022-04-01   15.0
8     C  2022-01-01    9.0
9     C  2022-02-01   19.0
10    C  2022-03-01   21.0
11    C  2022-04-01   23.0
```

Explanation:

- Use `groupby()` only on `type` (without `date`) so that all dates are in the group for a given `type`
- the `min_periods` argument ensures `rolling` works even for the first row where 2 periods are not available
- Use `assign()` to update the `value` column using index alignment.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

The below code does the work.

`rolling_sum = df.groupby(['type']).rolling(2).sum()`

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close -- just need to specify the level and set `drop=True` on `reset_index()`. Also, you can remove date from the groupby, since it's just grouped on type. You should use sort_values to ensure the input dataframe is in the correct order for the rolling sum.

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['type', 'date'])
df['rolling_sum'] = df.groupby(['type']).rolling(2).sum().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```